# I keep getting "password can't be blank" error when creating a new user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, authentication, activerecord, bcrypt

I'm creating what I thought was a simple user auth in a Rails API. I have searched every answer I can find here, and I simply can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. No matter what, when I try to create a new user, I get the error "password can't be blank."

Here is my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: {user: user}, status: 201
    else
      render json: {errors: user.errors.full_messages}
    end
  end

  private 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

My model, with validations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
  validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}, uniqueness: true

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: {on: :create}, confirmation: {case_sensitive: true}, length: {minimum: 8}
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

A test JSON object that keeps getting rejected:

```
{
    "name": "Jim Nobody",
    "email": "jim@anywhere.com",
    "password": "abc12345",
    "password_confirmation": "abc12345"
}
```

The error I keep getting:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Password can't be blank",
        "Password can't be blank",
        "Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)",
        "Password confirmation can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

I know there are other answers to this question, but I have combed them line by line, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. All the fields are permitted and spelled correctly, as far as I can see.

I would so appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you also post either the `params` being sent if you're testing this manually, or the test code itself if you're testing it properly?

Comment: When I test in rails console, I am able to pass validation, but when I enter this json object in Postman, I get the errors. That makes me feel that my problem must be in the controller file, not the model file. Json params:

Comment: `{"name":"Jim Nobody", "email":"jim@nowhere.com", "password":"12345678", "password_confirmation":"12345678"}`

Comment: Can you look at the rails server log and post an example request? That will usually include the params that are sent to the server.

Comment: Can you check you're not getting a `CSRF token authenticity` failure in your Rails log when making the request from Postman?

Comment: Do you have a `password_digest` attribute? [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) could be failing at: `record.errors.add(:password, :blank) unless record.password_digest.present?`

Comment: I do have `password_digest`. Turns out that the whole JSON object needs to be wrapped in a `user` object. That solved the problem. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi check your params in controller. Currently you are passing only Params. The params will be users.  Just try to use users params.

> { "users": { "name":"test" } }

Comment: This was it! My JSON object from the front-end needed to be wrapped in a `user` hash.

Comment: `{"user": {"name": "Somebody", "email": ".."...}} `

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rajkumar for the answer. Originally, my front end was sending a JSON object that looked like this:

```
{
  "name": "Someone",
  "password": "a_password",
  ...
}
```

But Rails was expecting one that was wrapped inside a `user` hash like this:

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Somebody",
    "password": "a_password",
    ...
  }
}
```

Thanks, everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is hardly a direct answer to your question, but in my opinion, it will help. Use this gem called [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). Basically, install it, then place `byebug` before the user save in the controller. When it executed the code, it will hang the server until you type continue in the server tab. Until you type continue, you can use the server tab just like a rails console and debug the current state of the params and more. Hopefully this helps you debug your issue.

Comment: Thanks for that! I turned out that when I checked my user.password, it was empty, even though I was passing it. I actually needed to wrap all of my json parameters inside a larger "user" parameter for them all to be recognized by the Rails side.